# Trying to compile a cpp file but command prompt saying file not found

Tags: c++, command, prompt

[image: picture command prompt]

I have downloaded the c++ compiler from MinGW also set the environment variables

Comment: <hello_world> is no valid filename. Try changing it to something like `helloWorld`

Comment: I don't know why it is not working says file not found

Comment: <hello_world >p.cpp means you want the command to read input from hello_world and write output to p.cpp. If you're unlucky you just deleted all the data in p.cpp

Comment: What does the `p.cpp` do? And if the programs expects a command line input, then you should be putting the data after the file name. Btw, I don't think that is the motive, as `g++` is for compiling and not running.

Comment: You should create a folder for your project and put its files  in that folder. I don't recommend placing it on the desktop. And also spend some time learning how to use the command line to avoid problems like this. Using < and > on the command line could  have destroyed your source file.

Comment: Try `g++ -o helloworld p.cpp` although why did you name the cpp file `p.cpp`? Not a good name.

Comment: This link may help teach you a little about how to use the command line on windows: [https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'<' and '>' are research characters for redirection and are not to be used in file names.

most likely in this case it is trying to read input from hello_world as it would be seeing `< hello_world` but not find the file

The `> p.cpp` would be attempting to  write any output to p.cpp, so may have replaced what you had in that file.